# Creating small, normal, large and xlarge android xml layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing an android application which has four layout folders. One folder for each small, normal, large and xlarge categories.

I'm using eclipse juno with the most recent adt updates.

I'm using LG LG-E400 for my small screen testing, HTC Sensation & Galaxy Note for normal, a Galaxy Tab 10.1 for xlarge.

How do I get Eclipse to show accurate screen layouts based on the four screen sizes shown above?

Why when I open one of my normal screen layouts does eclipse pre select Nexus One 3.7" 480 x 720 hdpi my htc sensation reports it is a normal screen size with high density, however the layout shown in eclipse is nothing close to how it looks on my actual phone.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For starters, the built-in editor in Eclipse is pretty bad, it almost always render something incorrectly. About the screen sizes and ratios I don't know much, but you probably need to configure the screen density as well as the pixel size to look more real.

Comment: i should have added that i have four drawable folders with ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi resoources in them which i thought i had created with the correct dimensions as specified by android developer site. some of the screens have been rendered quite accurately while others are nowhere close which is even harder to explain

Comment: In case the predefinitions don't match your device: You can create your own config. In Eclipse go "Window" menu > "Android Virtual Device Manager", there to the "Device Definitions" tab and hit the "New Device..." button. You need to know the values though. (quick google search says the Sensation is 540x960px 4.3")

Comment: those settings worked a treat for my normal size screens, now i just need settings for a generic large screen device

Comment: Even though the HTC Desire z is reporting as NORMAL and HDPI, the same as my HTC Sensation, the layouts on the Desire z are not correct. why is that? is it because the z is "normally" landscape not portrait?